# Django Multiple Dictionary Parsing

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I'm trying to parse the following data structure in my HTML.

```
{'GROUPS': {'Group1': [{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}, {'key1':'value3', 'key2':'value4'}], 'Group2': [{'key1':'value5','key2':'value6'}, {'key1':'value7', 'key2':'value8'}]}}
```

The parsing code that I have is as follows:

```
<tbody>
{% for group,data in data|get_value:"GROUPS" %} 
<tr>
    <td>{{ group }}</td>
    {% for v in data.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ v|get_value:"key1" }}</td>
        <td>{{ v|get_value:"key2" }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

get_value is the custom filter that I've written which basically takes the key and the data structure, and returns the value back.

But this isn't working. Can anyone help me figure out why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, for constant keys, you don't need a custom filter, this will work just fine:

```
{{ v.key1 }}
```

That said, `data['GROUPS']` is a dict, and you want to iterate over its `items`, like you did with `data`.

`data` is a list though and doesn't need that:

```
<tbody>
{% for group, data in data.GROUPS.items %} 
<tr>
    <td>{{ group }}</td>
    {% for v in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ v.key1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ v.key2 }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```